# Check count of a specific element inside a list in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a class called `Point` (representing an two-dimensional point) which consist of two integers, x and y.

I then add a few `Point` objects into a list: `List<Point> points`

I created a method that finds the first integer of a point object.

I want to find out how many times a point with the specific x integer is in the list. 
An example could be the list of point objects has tree points as:
Point(5,6), Point(6,6) and Point(5,6)

My goal is to find out that in the list it occurs two times than a Point with the x integer of 5 exists.

Comment: `var count = points.Count(point => point.X == 5)`

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment, @canton7 ;)

Comment: @Freddy you should always show the code you have attempted. That would help better in solving the issues you are facing.

Comment: @germi It's also almost certainly a duplicate, so answering is discouraged (and answers will probably be downvoted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Linq` for that

```cs
var count = points.Count(p => p.X == 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Linq expression:

```
points.Count(point => point.x == 5);
```